# not able to access list of file

Tags: list, file, model, upload

In the code block below i am ale to upload file from the list of model

```
public async Task\<IActionResult\> AddClaim(\[FromForm\] AddClaim claims)

 =\>i am able to upload file from this controller
this is my model
public string? Remarks { get; set; }
public decimal ClaimAmount { get; set; }
public IFormFile\[\]? ClaimsForm { get; set; } = null!;
public IFormFile\[\]? MedicalForm { get; set; } = null!;

public IActionResult GroupClaims(\[FromForm\]List\<AddClaim\> claims)  =\> but not for this
```

public IActionResult GroupClaims([FromForm]List<AddClaim> claims)  => but not for this